# Can i use a electrolytic capacitor in a microphone circuit

Tags: dc

I'm inserting a 50-100 mv 2000 hz tone into a microphone circuit for transceiver signal tracing. I have an electric mike and instructions say if the resistor is in place for the electric mike source(which it is), to insert a 1-10 mfd in series with the signal generator to  block the DC.(see attach)

Can I use a electrolytic cap in lieu of a ceramic for dc blocking at this frequency?

Will the electrolytic act as a diode for the sine wave tone?

[image]

Comment: As with most "*Can I...*" questions the answer is: it depends... You show no circuit, you do not give any detailed information about the components. It will probably work **but** if you're replacing a 100V ceramic capacitor working at 80 V with a tantalum cap rated for 20V then you might have problems. You provide no details so in the end it is anyone's guess really.

Comment: Please at least provide a schematic with an indication to the capacitor in question

Comment: If the positive side is always higher than the negative side you can. It will not work as well as a ceramic though.

Comment: And make up my mind ... electrolytic in header, tantalum in body of question... perhaps you mean polarized capacitor.

Comment: @Trevor - tantalum capacitors *are* electrolytic, there's no conflict there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton hmm.. I suppose...

Comment: Probably not, unless the output of your signal generator is always above the VTX to which the input is pulled... though given the resistance you might get away with it.  For that matter, you barely need your own capacitor given that the only thing on the outside of the included one is that resistor.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The output of the signal generator will always be _below_ +VTX so the capacitor can safely be installed the other way around (- to signal generator, + to MIKE_IN)

Comment: @Frosty Yes, that's a clever solution!  One more re-open vote and you can post it as an answer.

Comment: One last thing, since you mentioned tantalum caps. Tantalums have a mark/stripe/dot designating the anode (+) side of the capacitor which is the opposite of the band you see on diodes and the stripe/arrow on electrolytic caps. Be careful. Especially since tantalum caps like to catch fire when reverse biased.

Comment: Note that the required capacitance decreases as frequency increases - having a large enough capacitor is mostly about getting good low frequency response.  By 2 KHz you can probably get away with a smaller capacitor, which you might be more likely to have in your junk box in non-polarized form.  Using too small a capacitor will primarily just result in a weaker signal - if your generator has adjustable output amplitude you may be able to counteract that there.

Answer (score 2):

Given that MIKE_IN is tied to +VTX through the pull-up resistor R92 you can inject your low level audio signal through an electrolytic capacitor wired with the anode (+) side connected to MIKE_IN and the cathode connected to your signal generator output (signal generator ground needs to be connected to circuit ground too).